# How to add confirm addeventlistener to different view pages in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different views: edit.html.erb and create.html.erb
I want to add similar functionality onclick a checkbox on both the pages but want to avoid writing redundant code in both the files:

Currently what I am doing in both the files:
In create.html.erb

```
<script>
    function onclick (event) {
        var message = 'Are you sure ?';
        confirm(message) || event.preventDefault();
        }
    var elem = document.getElementById('create');
    elem.addEventListener('click', onclick);
</script>
```

In edit.html.erb

```
<script>
    function onclick (event) {
        var message = 'Are you sure ?';
        confirm(message) || event.preventDefault();
        }
    var elem = document.getElementById('edit');
    elem.addEventListener('click', onclick);
</script>
```

Ideally I want to have a js file where both these events can be captured when clicking on either create or edit instead of writing this method individually on both files. What is a good way to do DRY here.

Comment: It's not a link but a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it the same way that Rails UJS does - by adding an event listener that targets elements with a `data-confirm` attribute:

```js
function handleConfirm(e){
  if (!event.target.matches('[data-confirm]')){ return; };
  const attr = e.target.dataset.confirm;
  const message = attr.length > 0 ? attr : 'Are you sure ?';
  window.confirm(message) || e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleConfirm);
```

```html
<button>No confirmation</button>
<button data-confirm>Standard message</button>
<button data-confirm="REALLY???!!">A button with a custom text</button>
```

Comment: This snippet may not work on some browsers since snippets run in a cross-domain iframe.

Comment: In general if you want to improve your JS skills quickly then stop using IDs - which is something I have never understood why we lure beginners into as its a dead end.  Use classes and data/attribute based selectors to create resuable behaviors that can be used to augment anything. Inline JS (and inline script tags) is also a similiar crutch.

Comment: I am using webpack. What I did was ```javascript_pack_tag <file_name>``` and moved the code to a js file put in packs/<file_name>.js 
Will eventually help in scaling any more functionality to the page.

Comment: Check if you don't already have `import Rails from "@rails/ujs"` in your pack. Its included by default up until Rails 7 and already has a confirmation handler so that you double up.